# Connection string for MariaDB using ODBC

Tags: mariadb, odbc

What is the connection string for using MariaDB with ODBC?

I'm guessing it's something like

```
DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=LOCALHOST; PORT=3306; DATABASE=DatabaseName; UID=root; PASSWORD=password;OPTION=3;
```

[Connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) seems to show strings for MySQL but not MariaDB.

[MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-table-types-odbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-other-dbms/) seems to have a lot of connection strings for Access, SQL Lite, excel, etc ...

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

Although this is late answer, but MariaDB have that documented [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-odbc/#connection-parameters)

```
SQLWCHAR *ConnStr= L"Driver={MariaDB ODBC 2.0 Driver};Server=localhost;UID=odbc_user;PWD=odbc_pw;DB=odbc_test;Port=3306";
```